# WinForms EndInit() calling prematurely on inherited form

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, initialization

We have a unexpected problem with initialization of inherited forms. I am expecting this to work:

```
public class MyChildForm : BaseForm
{

    public MyChildForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public overrides void EndInit() {
        base.EndInit();

        //Do special tweaks to buttons on MyChildForm!
        DoYoAwesomeThang(myButton);
    }
}
```

However it crashes because the buttons on MyChildForm aren't initialized yet. On investigation it turns out this is due to the following sequence of events when we instantiate MyChildForm:

1. BaseForm constructor called
2. BaseForm.InitializeConstructor() called
3. BaseForm.InitializeConstructor triggers EndInit()
4. MyChildForm.EndInit() is called....

   ...but MyChildForm.InitializeComponent() hasn't called yet so I don't have my buttons!!

So I understand the problem, but I'm puzzled as to why I'm doing wrong. In the end I put the button tweaks inside the MyChildForm constructor after InitializeComponent() and this works, but I thought that sort of thing was the job of EndInit().

My questions:

1. Is it wrong to put the button tweaks inside EndInit()?
2. Is it not possible to implement EndInit() implemented on inherited forms?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

`EndInit` will be called multiple times as controls get initialized in a form.  At times, there will be controls that have not been initialized when `EndInit` is called.  Possibly, the `Loaded` event is what you're looking for.